# Casting/unboxing generic types

Tags: c#

Good day,

I have a class that is used to store a value of Type T that I don't know what the type will be until runtime. I want to unbox/cast, not sure what the correct term is, a specific type (in this case a nullable decimal) back to type object.

Please forgive my code layout:

The class snippet:

```
public abstract class Types
    {
        public class ValueField<T>
        {
            [XmlAttribute]
            public int TemplateID { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute]
            public int FieldID { get; set; }

            [XmlIgnore]
            [ScriptIgnore]
            public TemplateApprovalField Field { get; set; }

            [XmlIgnore]
            [ScriptIgnore]
            public InstanceTemplateActivityValues Values { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute]
            public T Value { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

The function snippet:

I am stuck at the line "values.Add((Types.ValueField)field);", don't know how to cast it. At that moment, var field is a Types.ValueField.

```
 Values = new Func<XmlDocument, List<Types.ValueField<object>>>(xml =>
 {
  List<Types.ValueField<object>> values = new List<Types.ValueField<object>>();

if (xml != null)
{
  foreach (XmlNode node in xml.SelectNodes("//Field"))
  {

    if (node.Attributes["Type"].Value == "Numeric")
      {
        var field = new Types.ValueField<decimal?>()
        {
          Field = ApprovalFields.Find(f => f.FieldID == int.Parse(node.Attributes["ID"].Value)),
          FieldID = int.Parse(node.Attributes["ID"].Value),
          TemplateID = int.Parse(node.SelectSingleNode("../@ID").Value)
        };
        field.Value = new Func<string, decimal?>(val =>
          {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
              return null;
            else
            {
              decimal parsed = 0;
              if (decimal.TryParse(val, out parsed))
                return parsed;
            }
            return null;
        })(node.InnerText);


      values.Add((Types.ValueField<object>)field); //This is where my problem occurs...
   }
 }


}
   return values;
   })(row["Form_Values"] != DBNull.Value ? 
      new XmlDocument() { InnerXml =  row["Form_Values"].ToString() } : null)
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Regards
YP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a `ValueField<decimal?>`. That *isn't* a `ValueField<object>` - your `ValueField<T>` class isn't covariant in `T`, and couldn't be. (Classes can't be covariant, and your API includes `T` in "in" positions too.)

To demonstrate why this *mustn't* work:

```
 Value<decimal?> foo = new Value<decimal?>();
 Value<object> bar = foo; // Imagine this worked
 bar.Value = "hello";
 decimal? x = foo.Value;
```

What would you expect that to do? Everything other than the second line is above reproach, so we *must* make the second line fail, which it does.

The simple answer here is to create a `Value<object>` in the first place, instead of a `Value<decimal?>`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the quick response. Will quickly check.

Comment: where do you stay so that I can give you a big fat open mouth kiss... :) Thanks for the good explanation. Fixed.